# FormData object is empty when logged or alerted

Tags: jquery, angularjs, summernote

I am using AngularJS along and angular-summernote as an editor.
My HTML:

```
{{msg}}

<form id="sampleForm" ng-submit="sendFormData()" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label>Text:</label>
    <summernote height="300" ng-model="summerNoteText" on-image-upload="imageUpload(files)"></summernote><br><br>


    <label>Text box:</label>
    <input type="text" name="normaltext">
    <input type="hidden" name="summernotetext" value="{{summerNoteText}}">


    <button type="submit">
        Submit
    </button>

</form>
```

my controller for this page:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('postTestbench')

    .controller('MainFormController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.msg = "submit nigga";

        $scope.imageUpload = function (files) {
            var data = new FormData($('form')[0]);
            data.append('file', files[0]);

            console.log(data);
        };
    }]);
```

Can you tell me any problem here? I have searched docs of jquery and developer mozilla, they are suggesting the same code.

I just want to upload an image from summernote and want to get the image url from the server, 
but the FormData object data is showing empty.

> Update

the config file where i am assigning the controller to this page:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('postTestbench', ['ngRoute', 'summernote'])

    .config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider

        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'pages/sampleForm.html',
            controller: 'MainFormController'
        })

        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        })
    })

;
```

Comment: Where are you bootstrapping your app? where are you assigning this controller to template?

Comment: Try giving your form a 'name' not just an 'id'.

Comment: I have updated the question....... and provided the js file code where i am assigning the controller @TJ

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your `data` is not empty, just inspect it correctly by `formData.entries`.

[FormData Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/entries):

> The FormData.entries() method returns an iterator allowing to go through all key/value pairs contained in this object. The key of each pair is a USVString object; the value either a USVString, or a Blob.

Here is how to inspect form data:

```
var data = new FormData($('form')[0]);
data.append('file', files[0]);

for (var [key, value] of data.entries()) {
    console.log(key, value);
}
```

Comment: Maybe*. Because less than 6 characters edit suggests are not allowed. :D

Comment: yes, I have tried.... it's onle showing: n e
...and nothing....please help.... @YinGang

Comment: I have tried the exact code. But the output is:
n e
which means a key=n
and a value=e
I have never appended this key value pair

Comment: Do you have any other `<form>`? It really works at this [live demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/dEsJoY?p=preview).Or update this demo to your code?

Comment: And if you just to upload image, try `new FormData()` rather than `new FormData($('form')[0]);`

Comment: And [here is another demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/BV3eDB?p=preview), suggestion of how to upload.